# What special cards are used with Eithné's ability?

Tags: gwent

[image: Eithné card in Gwent open beta]

Eithné's ability says:

> Resurrect a Bronze or Silver special card.

If I understand correctly, special cards are cards that are not played to any specific row. The wikia has [a list of them](https://gwent.gamepedia.com/Special_cards). What cards are typically synergistic with other Scoia'tael cards, so that they are played through Eithné's ability? Examples from popular decks are encouraged.